# open html file as byte array and display on browser

Tags: c#

I have code that convert word document or excel document to html files then open it using the code below. However, the code below only opens html file for word document for excel file, it keeps looking for something else at a different location sheet.html instead of the main html. I did notice that with word document, there is not tab. But with excel there's tab and sheet.html. So may be that is the case. If so, how do i use the code below to open a converted to html file from excel? Thank you all for your help

```
 byte[] bytes;
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(htmlFilePath.ToString(), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fs);
        bytes = reader.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
        fs.Close();
    }
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    Response.Flush();
```

and here is the code that i use to convert to html from excel file

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass excelApplicationClass = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();


        excelApplicationClass.Workbooks.Open(destination,
                                             Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                             Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                             Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                             Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        excelApplicationClass.Visible = false;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workBook = excelApplicationClass.ActiveWorkbook;

        workBook.SaveAs(htmlFilePath, XlFileFormat.xlHtml);
        workBook.Close();
```

Comment: Presumably the file is saved to multiple HTML files and images.  You need to work out which one you actually want, or package it up in some other way.  As an aside, using Interop in an automation scenario like this is [not recommended or supported](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/257757).

Comment: can you let me know why it's not recommended? thank you

Comment: The link I gave you has an exhaustive list of reasons.  There are other managed code options available (and I'm certain some will save a workbook to a single html file).

Answer (score 0):

If you've converted it to a html file, why not just use [Process.Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca(v=vs.110).aspx) to open it?

Comment: i just tried it, it opened the file fine but it will open it up in new tab instead of current tab. Also, after opens it i would like to delete those html and its related files immediately.